# How upload images and arrays on express server with Multer?

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, multer

I'm trying to 'save' on my express server a Product (name, description, price), a list of codes and list of images) using an HTTP post (angular).

```
JSON.stringify(product) // stringify the array that contains name description..
JSON.stringify(codes)
imageFiles: File[] // array of images
```

with a for loop, I append to a var FromData each item of imageFiles and then I append the others 2 stringified arrays.

I was trying more solution to achieve my goal:

1. save in DB the info stored in the arrays
2. after that save the images on the server

to parse the req with files I'm using Multer:

CASE A:

```
router.post("/newProduct", upload.array('images[]', 10), function (req, res, next) {
  // first: middleware is executed the images are loaded
  // in the req.body I find the other 2 arrays to store in the DB
  // but if something with the DB fails, I still have the images saved (I DONT WANT IT)
});
```

CASE B:

```
router.post("/newProduct",  function (req, res, next) {
  upload.array('images[]', 10)(req, res, next);
  // here i can't access req.body anymore because I'm outside multer that can parse what is stores in the request
});
```

Some ideas about it ??

Answer (score 1):

You should validate your Data before processing your images, so if your data validation is failed, images are not uploaded.
here you have 2 options

1. use Multer Config to validate data before multer saved the file.
2. (better option) create a middleware for data validation, so that multer only uploads when you have performed all data validation and you know it won't fail.

so here is the example for multer single file upload and multifile upload with proper configuration of multer and an example middleware if you want the option 2

```
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');

// first create a multer config
const StorageConfig = multer.diskStorage({

    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        // here you can validate all data from your request object
        try{
            // some thing like following. and in case of failure of data validation raise a call back with error
            if(typeof req.body.ImageFor == "undefined"){
                return cb(new Error('Uploading Image for  is Required, 1 for MAIN image, 2 for Thumbnale'))
            }
            else if(req.body.ImageFor !=1 && req.body.ImageFor!= 2){
                return cb(new Error('Invalid value for ImageFor, 1 for MAIN image, 2 for Thumbnale'))
            }
            var dir="";
            // adjust your storage path according to your requirements
            // can be as simply as uploads/ 
            // (done forget to create the directory else MULTER will throw error)
            dir = 'uploads/' + req.body.ProductID + '/' + req.body.ImageFor + '/';
            cb(null, dir);   

        }
        catch(err){
            console.log('error', err);
        }
        
    },
    // define your file name the way you like. 
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        // save file as current UTC tile 
        //let extArray = file.mimetype.split("/");
        //let extension = extArray[extArray.length - 1];
        //cb(null,getUTCTime()+ '.'+ extension);
        cb(null,file.originalname);
    }
});

// define the File filters , what type of files you want to accept.
const fileFilters=(req,file,cb)=>{
    if(file.mimetype==='image/jpeg' || file.mimetype ==='image/png'){
        cb(null, true);
    }
    else{
        cb(null, false);
    }
}

// lets create our multer objects 
const Multerupload = multer({ storage: StorageConfig,fileFilter: fileFilters});

// now here is your API Call 

router.post('/UploadFile',Multerupload.single('imageFieldName'),(req,res,next) =>{
        // process your data here if needed    
});

//=========================================

// Multer also supports Multi file upload 
// so lets create a multi file upload in single call,
// multer will need fields array with limit so lets define that 
// following will allow uploading of 10 images of each (change fields according your call)
var upLoadFields = [
    { name:'productMainImage', maxCount: 10 },
    { name: 'productSmallImage', maxCount: 10 },
    { name: 'productSideImage', maxCount: 10 },
    { name: 'productThumbnale', maxCount: 10 }
];

// now lets create a multi upload API

router.post('/UploadMulti',Multerupload.fields(upFields),(req,res,next) =>{
        // process your data here if needed    

});
```

I recommend creating a Middleware for data processing before multer uploads/process the files, in that middle where you can validate/ save/ fetch data from DB etc, and only move to next(), when you are happy, and multer will process the files.

so here is an example for option 2 (middleware)

```
//====================
    // ######### Method 2 better way (I think)#########
    // ideally the data validation should be done in a middleware, 
    // 
    
    // so above multi-upload call will change to following 

    const ValidateData = require('../middlewares/Datavalidator');

    router.post('/UploadMulti',ValidateData,MultiuploadFile.fields(upFields),(req,res,next) =>{
    });
    
    //----------------- here is the simple how you will create a middlewere
    // Create a new file called Datavalidator in some directory, I am using middlewares as the directory name
    // and in the file do something like following 
    
    module.exports = (req,res,next) =>{
        var responseObject={};
        if(typeof req.body.ImageFor == "undefined"){
            // change the status according to your need, i am using 500 = internal server error just for example 
            responseObject.status = 500;
            responseObject.message= 'ImageFor is required';
            return res.status(responseObject.status).json(responseObject);
        }
        else if(!(req.body.ImageFor ==1 && req.body.ImageFor==2)){
            responseObject.status = 500;
            responseObject.message= 'ImageFor Value is in correct';
            return res.status(responseObject.status).json(responseObject); 
        }
next();
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

use [express-file-upload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload) . its easier way to maintain upload functionallity on express.